# Wpf Application to Web Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to know if you can convert an app written in WPF (C#) to a web application, using a code conversion tool?

Comment: it can be done. but not one setup tool. you need to re-code your user interface.

Comment: Normally you use MVVM pattern in WPF. If you did that the viewmodels and models can be reused for web application. The GUI has to be converted to web controls.

Comment: I know you will be able to use it in windows 10 soon :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no tool to do this kind conversion. But you can reuse your code to create a web application in Silverlight (but beware, it is not supported by some browsers). Otherwise, you can get a look here [C#/XAML for HTML5](http://www.cshtml5.com/)

Comment: very interesting, even though I was looking for a solution together to create apps for PC (style Windows.Forms) and web. Thank you!