# How to call Windows form from .net web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i have a windows application and now we want to upgrade it to web application. 
Is there any way to use same forms from web application 
to avoid duplicate work to develop same page in web application. 
i want to open windows form on one click from web form. please provide any sample code if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wpf Application to Web Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998692/wpf-application-to-web-application)

Answer (score 1):

It's not something you can do automatically. You can reuse your business logic behind the application but you have to write a new UI from scratch. You can also try to use some automated tools but to be honest in most cases you will have to put significant amount of work to get your application working the same as window windows application. You must consider and implement new security policy regarding data transfer/presentation in your web app.

Answer (score 0):

As Adjorem said, simply, no. Even if you find a converter it will probably make a mess and you'll need to do a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

To open your windows app from web app:
You can register your own url protocol to start your application, e.g myfancyapp.
On your website you can create an href="myfancyapp://...". You can parameterize your windows app through a downloadable file with startup infos.

See:
[How do I register a custom URL protocol in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows)

If you want, you can check, if your app is installed with the help of fonts. Install a font (with a special name) with your app installer. You can then check if font is available on your website and display a message "Please install windows app first".